# convert string to dictionary in swift 5?

Tags: swift, string, nsdictionary, swift5

I have a string which contains a json in the following format:

`var myString: String = "{key1: val1, key2: val2}"`

How can I convert this to:

`var myJson: [String: String] = ["key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"]`

Since my string is not in format `"{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}"`, I am facing difficulty in parsing it through the following code snippet:

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This function always returns nil for myString

Comment: You don't have valid JSON, that's why. Where dos your string comes from? The issue might be there...

Comment: @Larme It's coming in this format from the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have to do it the hard way. Something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    func trim() -> String {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                let myString: String = "{key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3}"
                let myJson = transform(myString)
                print("----> myJson: \(myJson)")
            }
    }
    
    func transform(_ myString: String) -> [String : String] {
        var result = [String : String]()
        if myString.count > 2 { // case of {}
            let temp1 = myString.dropFirst().dropLast()
            let temp2 = temp1.split(separator: ",").map{String($0)}
            for str in temp2 {
                let temp3 = str.split(separator: ":").map{String($0)}
                let (k,v) = (temp3[0].trim(),temp3[1].trim())
                result[k] = v
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know you should quote keys and values. Here is a easy way.

```
let jsonString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\w+)", with: "\"$1\"", options: .regularExpression)

let result = convertToDictionary(text: jsonString)
```